# Nodejs check if the given string is a valid file system path without actually checking the file system

Tags: node.js, file, path, filesystems, file-exists

How in nodejs can I check if the given string is a valid filesystem path without actually checking the filesystem.

I am using telegram bot nodejs api and when sending files it checks if the file exist or not. But on the second time I am using the `telegram file id` that i got from the previews upload and not the actual file path to send the file, so in this case i want to check if the string is a actual file path and not a file id(exp: `AgADBAADuqcxG-ysuwhqkRaOdVnJI0CZXhkABL1NBSyVlK3gduoAAgI`) before checking if file exist so to increase performance and avoid unnecessary file system access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.**

You could check if the string equals `path.basename(string)`. Then it doesn't contain any path separators and is definitely not a file in another directory. That funtion doesn't go touch the filesystem and only inspects the string for platforms specific directory separator, and hence suits your performance needs.

```
string === path.basename(string)
```

**2.**

Another idea: if the identifiers follow a specific format, then create a regexp for the format and test each string for a match and proceed accordingly.

```
/identifierregex/.test(string)
```

Comment: i was hopping for a generic way but both of these would work as well, tnx

Comment: shoot, i forgot about the existence of `path.sep`, you could check if your string contains that character, then it probably is a filename

Comment: @pspi  `.` or `..` is also a path, so the first approach would fail.